# Garmin HRM Dual, not transmitting data over BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, garmin

For some reason device does not transmit data (heart rate) over BLE. It connects fine, phone app is also able to discover services and connect to service.

I started up with iOS and Health app and actually saw some data coming through, so, it worked initially. Later, created the base for the BLE connectivity on Android app, it connected just fine, discovered the correct services and connected to these. And no data. Re-checked with iOS, also silence. Assuming that it is device'd problem (faulty sensors etc), took it to the shop I purchased it from. Tested it, worked like a charm with ANT+. So, it has to be BLE issue. The code itself is pretty much sample code from Android dev guides.

{

```
//0x180D - heart rate service
//0x2A37 - heart rate characteristic

private static HrmHandler instance;

private static UUID UUID_HRM_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private static UUID UUID_HRM_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString("00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

private static String LOG_TAG = HrmHandler.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice mBtDevice;

private String mBtDeviceAddress;

private Context mContext;

public static HrmHandler getInstance() {

    if (instance == null)
        instance = new HrmHandler();
    return instance;
}


public void connect(Context ctx) {

    mContext = ctx;
    BluetoothManager bt_manager = (BluetoothManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

    mBtAdapter = bt_manager.getAdapter();

    if (mBtAdapter == null || !mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) return;

    mBtAdapter.startLeScan(new UUID[] {UUID_HRM_SERVICE}, this);
}

public void disconnect() {
}

@Override
public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Found HRM device " + device.getName());

    mBtDevice = device;
    mBtAdapter.stopLeScan(this);

    mBtDeviceAddress = mBtDevice.getAddress();

    mBtDevice.connectGatt(mContext, false,this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
    super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, String.format("Connection state change, new state %d", newState));
    if (mBtDeviceAddress == null || !mBtDeviceAddress.equals(gatt.getDevice().getAddress()))
        return; //we are not interested about that connection state

    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Device connected");
        gatt.discoverServices();
        return;
    }

    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Device disconnected");
        return;
    }

}

@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

    if (gatt != null) {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = null;

        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();

        for (BluetoothGattService s : services) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, String.format("Discovered %s, uuid %s", s.toString(), s.getUuid().toString()));
        }

        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID_HRM_SERVICE);

        if (service != null)
            characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID_HRM_CHARACTERISTIC);
        gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

    }

}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

    if (!UUID_HRM_CHARACTERISTIC.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "READ: Not interesting characteristic " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
        return;
    }

    int flags = characteristic.getProperties();
    int format = (flags & 0x01) != 0 ? BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16 : BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;

    int heart_rate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, String.format("Heart rate %d bpm", heart_rate) );
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);


    if (!UUID_HRM_CHARACTERISTIC.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "CHANGED: Not interesting characteristic " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
        return;
    }

    gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
}
```

Can anyone help me forward, especially someone at Garmin, or is it common and known issue and I just should forget about it and try to go forward with ANT+?

Comment: If you would like notifications, then you must write to the Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor in order to enable the remote device to send notifications.